# Is setting var _ = this bad practice in javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I was looking through some open source code the other day and noticed they used `var _ = this;` to maintain a reference to the original this. Now as a novice in Javascript I was wondering if this is bad practice?

I have seen and used `self = this`, `that = this`, `me = this`, however the use of the underscore makes the code easier to read in my eyes. Especially since in the plugin I'm writing requires it's use often. My eyes can focus on the actually variable/function more easily.

Now my question to you all is how do you feel about using `_ = this;`

Here is the code I was referring to.

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js

Comment: As long as you're consistent and not causing a conflict with other code used in your project, I don't see a problem. What would be bad is if you used a different identifier every time.

Comment: I do prefer something longer and auto-explicative, like `self`

Comment: @PaulS. A different identifier every time can be good if it's *expressive* and consistent. `self` and `me` aren't, particularly. But if you're dealing with a `Thing` and you call it `theThing`, and dealing with a `Foo` and call it `theFoo`...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true, that would be consistent and helpful if you have a closure needing access to two different ones at the same time, but usually I try to be more generic so e.g. if the name of `Foo` became `Bar` in some later revision, there's no worry of renaming every `theFoo` to `theBar` as well.

Comment: @PaulS.: :-) I'm bothered by how much I'm liking the idea of using `_`...

Comment: This is totally a matter of opinion, which isn't the right fit for StackOverflow, but FWIW in some other languages  (Erlang, Go, Nim, etc), `_` is used to denote a value that will not be used.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: `_` is also the main object in underscore/lodash libraries, if the project uses one of those, it's probably best to leave `_` alone.

Comment: @xanatos: if you are refactoring code like this and forget the `var self = ...` line, you'll be stepping over the global `window.self` instead of getting an error. That can be quite tricky to debug.

Comment: I think that the mere fact that many (most?) developers would expect a var `_` to refer to the underscore/lodash library makes this a pretty bad convention to follow.

Comment: @roippi: Meh, Underscore [doesn't have the penetration people sometimes think](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/javascript_library/all). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - That page appears to list Underscore but not Lodash. I wonder if it would be different if both were included? Most devs I know these days are using Lodash instead of Underscore. Maybe still not a huge number, but Underscore by itself is probably understating it.

Answer (score 1):

The question here is if you really need to do that.

Let's suppose that you have an object that call another lassing a callback.

Now with the variable _ you could have something like this:

```
function Person( name ) {
  var _ = this;
  _.name = name;

  _.dog = new Dog( "fido" );
  _.dog.goEat( function() {
     // do something when dog finished to eat
     _.goOutWithYourDog( );
  } );

  ...
```

In this case you can do the same without use the _.

```
function Person( name ) {
      this.name = name;

      this.dog = new Dog( "fido" );
      this.dog.goEat( function() {
         // do something when dog finished to eat
         this.goOutWithYourDog( );
      }.bind(this) );

      ...
```

Using bind you can wrap your function and use inside it this as Person object.

You can also use the closer with bind, so you let the callback function have the context binded by the caller, but you can use  the Person object.
This os usefull when you have to use callback for events. Better of use _ because you use it only if you need it.

```
function Person( name ) {
      this.name = name;
      (function(person){
        $( ... ).on( "click", function( e ) {
           var value = this.value;
           person.doSomeStuffWithTheValue( value );
        } );
      })( this );
```

Comment: Hope this can be helpful

Comment: In your last example, you don't need the IIFE. There's already a perfectly good variable scope. You're just using another function and doing basically the same thing that you'd do without it.

Comment: If I use bind in this example, you can't use this into the click callback as the Node Object. The last example use the closure in order to have both this and person object into the callback function.

Comment: If you use the _ variable, your intent is to use it everytime you have to use a callback, but what I want to say with that example is that you can do the same without a scope variable, because the scope variable is a pattern of common usage, wich sometimes is abused..

Comment: interesting. I still have a lot to learn in regards to Javascript and its OOP concepts. I am creating a jquery plugin and I actually bind the jQuery object to the closer. It seems as I have much more research to do in regards to variable scope and understanding closers